# I use this code for infinite scrolling using selenium, and Python, but it was not scrolled infinitely

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, web-crawler, infinite-scroll

I am new to selenium, and wanna crawl a website(https://shopping.naver.com/living/homeliving/category?menu=10004487&sort=POPULARITY).

This page needs to be scroll through, so I refer to this code:

```
import time

SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME = 1

# Get scroll height
last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")

while True:
    # Scroll down to bottom
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

    # Wait to load page
    time.sleep(SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME)

    # Calculate new scroll height and compare with last scroll height
    new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    if new_height == last_height:
        break
    last_height = new_height
```

However, **the problem is in this page it is scrolled only once by this code.** How come this happen? How can I fix the code for infinite scrolling?

Please comment, and thank you in advance. :)

**+ It does work but not the end of the scroll!**

Comment: In my computer,it truly can infinite scrolling.No problem.

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA OH It does work. But not until the end of the scroll. :(